# Alternative to std::vector to store a sequence of objects

Tags: c++, boost, stdvector

I am dealing with several million data elements that are to be accessed sequentially. The elements rarely grow and shrink but do so in known chunk sizes in a predictable manner.

I am looking for a efficient collection similar to std::vector which does not reallocate but holds the data in multiple chunks of memory. Whenever I push more objects in to the collection and if the last chunk is exhausted, then a new chunk gets created and populated. I am not keen to have a random access operator. I cannot use std::list due to performance issues and few other issues that are beyond the scope of the question at hand.

Is there a ready made collection that fits my requirement in boost or any other library. I want to make sure that there is nothing that is available of the shelf before I try and cook something myself.

Comment: Have you tried `std::deque`?

Comment: How about something like `std::vector< std::array<T, CHUNK_SIZE> > v;`?

Comment: @nogard: Yes deque is a good alternative but is good when insertions and deletions happen only near the beginning and end. Also, it is not a good alternative when I think of the data in terms of chunks.

Comment: @jrok: Nice idea. However, the chunk size is not a constant. I will prefer std::vector<std::deque<T>> or something on those lines.

Comment: Then you'd might want to rephrase "fixed chunks" in your Q. It's what got me thinking the size of chunks is constant.

Comment: @jrok, you are right. I have made the changes. What I meant was the chunk size is in a known range and is determined at runtime and not at compile time.

Comment: I think you'll have to write your own.  Perhaps using a vector of vector under the hood.

Comment: Wait, aren't inserts at an end?   Why is deque not the answer?

Comment: Actually, reading it again, do you just want a vector of chunks?

Comment: If you only need to access the elements sequentially, why is `std::list` not the answer?  Or is the problem that its just mostly sequential and the occasional random access make `std::list` too slow?

Comment: @MooingDuck am planning to use a vector of deques. Each deque is the chunk that I have in mind.
ChrisDodd std::list is dog slow when compared to deque or a vector. In the application problem domain, the delay is not acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds to me like your best bet would be many `std::vector`s stored within a B-Tree. The B-Tree lets you refer to areas in memory without actually visiting them during tree traversal, allowing for minimal file access.

Comment: Not a bad idea. However, I have written an implementation using vector of deque (as chunk) and it works great.